# How to construct an XML document out of an XPATH Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have the following xpath:

```
/Parent/Children/child
```

My goal is to construct the following XML document based solely off the xpath above:

```
<Parent>
  <Children>
    <child></child>
  </Children>
</Parent>
```

How can I accomplish my goal using Java?

Comment: How did you envision creating *that* XML from *that* XPath? Where are all the value coming from?

Comment: *"How can I accomplish my goal using Java?"* Parse the xpath string, then build the XML hierarchy, e.g. using DOM, and output that to text with indentation. Which part of all that are you asking about? Those are at least 3 different questions.

Comment: I guess all 3 of the subquestions you mentioned. I want to see how someone would implement the question I asked above. I usually use jaxb or some framework but I'd like to see a proper implementation of such task.

Comment: *"I want to see how someone would implement the question I asked above."* So this is a "**write the code for me**" request? Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: No, I have an implementation using jaxb but it's a lot of code to put for such a question. I wanted to see how someone implement this without using jaxb or some other framework.

Comment: How can you have JAXB code for this? JAXB code is very static, against a well-known XML. You're asking about the build dynamic XML from an arbitrary XPath. That cannot be done with JAXB.

Comment: The solution isn't entirely generic but you can use a map object to have the keys as xpaths and the value as the values for the xpath. Which is why earlier I had an XML example with values (console output). Then you can use jaxb to marshall/unmarshall objects to XML. This isn't ideal which is why I was asking for a proper implementation here, for my knowledge not to steal but to learn

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using xslt transformation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="path" select="'/Parent/Children/child'"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="createstructure">
            <xsl:with-param name="xpath" select="$path"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="createstructure">
        <xsl:param name="xpath" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="elementname">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($xpath, '/')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(replace($xpath, '^/', ''), '/')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($xpath)"/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$elementname}">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($xpath, '/')">
                    <xsl:call-template name="createstructure">
                        <xsl:with-param name="xpath" select="substring-after(replace($xpath, '^/', ''), '/')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```